# How to bind a property to an external controller?

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I work with the SDK 10.6, with Xcode 4.2.

I want to bind a "property" to a controller that exists "out of my nib". How could I do :

- with Interface Builder ?
- without it ?

More precisely, I want to bind the `enabled` property of a `NSButton` to an arrayController that exists "out of my nib". The only objects to which I can bind properties, in interface builder, are the placeholders or the objects. But :

- I cannot change the placeholders.
- If I had an arrayController to my NIB, it will be created when my NIB is loaded.

Why am I in this situation ? Because : the arrayController is in my NIB ; but the button is in another NIB. This second NIB is a subview of my main view.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found an answer.

Some notations :

- `MySubiewController` and `MySubiewController.xib` are the couple of objets where I want to perform some bindings. They have to be thought as a subview.
- Somewhere else in my program, "above", I have already an `myMainArrayController`. It is an `ArrayController`, linked with my data, and "created in my main view".

Now : the answer.

- First, for instance via the `init` method of `MySubiewController`, store your `myMainArrayController` in some variable (you have to expose this variable in the `.h`, as a `@property` (it's better) before using it in your program). Let's give the same name to this variable (you could give any name). For instance :

  ```
   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
                 bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
    withArrayController:(NSArrayController *)anArrayController
  {
      NSLog(@"Creation of an instance of MySubiewController");


      self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
      if (self) {
          myMainArrayController = anArrayController ;
      }

      return self;
  }
  ```

  This is where you will tell to your "subview" who is the `arrayController` already exisiting.
- Do your bindings with `File's Owner` and then `self.myMainArrayController`.
- That's it!!! It should work!